# Smoke Test- "unable to obtain Resolver Configuration" in app-investigate and app-search

Tags: smoke-testing

When running the Smoke Test for setting up the training environment, he following error appears in app-investigate:

"2018-11-20 10:56:37.104  INFO 1724 --- [t-dispatcher-26] c.q.q.c.p.QuanfigurableActorConfigurer   : Unable to initialise Investigation, unable to obtain Resolver Configuration, reason: quanfiguration: No routees available.
2018-11-20 10:56:49.860 ERROR 1724 --- [lt-dispatcher-4] akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy             : Request to retrieve 'resolverConfigMemento' failed. "

and in app-search:

"Unable to initialise Search, unable to obtain Resolver Configuration, reason: quanfiguration: No routees available. "

Does anyone know what might be causing the problem? Thank you!